# Tensorflow Confusion Matrix in TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I want to have a visual of confusion matrix in tensorboard. To do this, I am modifying Evaluation example of Tensorflow Slim: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py

In this example code, Accuracy already provided but it is not possible to add "confusion matrix" metric directly because it is not streaming.

**What is difference between streaming metrics and non-streaming ones?**

Therefore, I tried to add it like this:

```
c_matrix = slim.metrics.confusion_matrix(predictions, labels)

#These operations needed for image summary
c_matrix = tf.cast(c_matrix, uint8)
c_matrix = tf.expand_dims(c_matrix, 2)
c_matrix = tf.expand_dims(c_matrix, 0)

op = tf.image_summary("confusion matrix", c_matrix, collections=[])
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, op)
```

This creates an image in tensorboard but probably there is a formatting problem. Matrix should be normalized between 0-1 so that It produces meaningful image.

**How can I produce a meaningful confusion matrix? How can I deal with multi batch evaluation process?**

Comment: A bit late in the discussion, but you might be interested in https://github.com/cheind/tf-matplotlib which provides a generic way to generate plots and has also support for confusion matrices. The confusion matrix code is inspired by @mlninja's response.

Comment: I adapted the solution above to work with the new estimator API: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/227#issuecomment-397857872

Answer (score 46):

Here is something I have put together That works reasonably well. Still need to adjust a few things like the tick placements etc.

[image: Confusion Matrix as Image in Tensorflow]

Here is the function that will pretty much do everything for you.

```
from textwrap import wrap
import re
import itertools
import tfplot
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix



def plot_confusion_matrix(correct_labels, predict_labels, labels, title='Confusion matrix', tensor_name = 'MyFigure/image', normalize=False):
''' 
Parameters:
    correct_labels                  : These are your true classification categories.
    predict_labels                  : These are you predicted classification categories
    labels                          : This is a lit of labels which will be used to display the axix labels
    title='Confusion matrix'        : Title for your matrix
    tensor_name = 'MyFigure/image'  : Name for the output summay tensor

Returns:
    summary: TensorFlow summary 

Other itema to note:
    - Depending on the number of category and the data , you may have to modify the figzie, font sizes etc. 
    - Currently, some of the ticks dont line up due to rotations.
'''
cm = confusion_matrix(correct_labels, predict_labels, labels=labels)
if normalize:
    cm = cm.astype('float')*10 / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    cm = np.nan_to_num(cm, copy=True)
    cm = cm.astype('int')

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
###fig, ax = matplotlib.figure.Figure()

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(7, 7), dpi=320, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
im = ax.imshow(cm, cmap='Oranges')

classes = [re.sub(r'([a-z](?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?=[A-Z][a-z]))', r'\1 ', x) for x in labels]
classes = ['\n'.join(wrap(l, 40)) for l in classes]

tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))

ax.set_xlabel('Predicted', fontsize=7)
ax.set_xticks(tick_marks)
c = ax.set_xticklabels(classes, fontsize=4, rotation=-90,  ha='center')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()

ax.set_ylabel('True Label', fontsize=7)
ax.set_yticks(tick_marks)
ax.set_yticklabels(classes, fontsize=4, va ='center')
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
ax.yaxis.tick_left()

for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
    ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], 'd') if cm[i,j]!=0 else '.', horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=6, verticalalignment='center', color= "black")
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
summary = tfplot.figure.to_summary(fig, tag=tensor_name)
return summary
```

#

And here is the rest of the code that you will need to call this functions.

```
''' confusion matrix summaries '''
img_d_summary_dir = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "summaries", "img")
img_d_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(img_d_summary_dir, sess.graph)
img_d_summary = plot_confusion_matrix(correct_labels, predict_labels, labels, tensor_name='dev/cm')
img_d_summary_writer.add_summary(img_d_summary, current_step)
```

Confuse away!!!

Comment: Works nicely thanks. I had an error with sklearn confusion matrix function not accepting labels argument but luckily it doesn't need that argument so I removed it and all works good now.

Comment: @Burton2000, Feel free to edit and make the code better

Comment: GUys,, Check out this link. This is a better implementation of same code.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/227

Comment: This answer is not related with the question anyway, it is a completely another solution

Comment: Nice solution. I found that I had to add `ax.set_ylim(len(cm)-0.5, -0.5)` to stop it from cropping the top and bottom rows of the CM.

Answer (score 20):

Here's how I produced and displayed a "streaming" confusion matrix for test code (returned `test_op` is evaluated for each batch to test on).

```
def _get_streaming_metrics(prediction,label,num_classes):

    with tf.name_scope("test"):
        # the streaming accuracy (lookup and update tensors)
        accuracy,accuracy_update = tf.metrics.accuracy(label, prediction, 
                                               name='accuracy')
        # Compute a per-batch confusion
        batch_confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(label, prediction,
                                             num_classes=num_classes,
                                             name='batch_confusion')
        # Create an accumulator variable to hold the counts
        confusion = tf.Variable( tf.zeros([num_classes,num_classes], 
                                          dtype=tf.int32 ),
                                 name='confusion' )
        # Create the update op for doing a "+=" accumulation on the batch
        confusion_update = confusion.assign( confusion + batch_confusion )
        # Cast counts to float so tf.summary.image renormalizes to [0,255]
        confusion_image = tf.reshape( tf.cast( confusion, tf.float32),
                                  [1, num_classes, num_classes, 1])
        # Combine streaming accuracy and confusion matrix updates in one op
        test_op = tf.group(accuracy_update, confusion_update)

        tf.summary.image('confusion',confusion_image)
        tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)

    return test_op,accuracy,confusion
```

After you process all the data batches by running `test_op` , you can simply look up the final confusion matrix (within your session) by `confusion.eval()` or `sess.eval(confusion)` if you prefer.

Comment: When I try this, the summary image I get is corresponds to the initialisation of the variable (zeros). If I use `confusion_update` it seems to be working though. Any idea why?

Comment: You are assigning the `batch_confusion` to `confusion_update`, hence the `confusion_image` is not updated at all and your summary stays as was initialized.

Comment: This should be selected as final solution @user2616232

Answer (score 6):

Here is something that works with tf.contrib.metrics.MetricSpec (when you use Estimator). It is inspired from Jerod's answer and the metric_op.py source file. You get a streamed confusion matrix with percentages :

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops,dtypes
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops,variables

def _createLocalVariable(name, shape, collections=None, 
validate_shape=True,
              dtype=dtypes.float32):
  """Creates a new local variable.
  """
  # Make sure local variables are added to 
  # tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES
  collections = list(collections or [])
  collections += [ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]
  return variables.Variable(
  initial_value=array_ops.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype),
  name=name,
  trainable=False,
  collections=collections,
  validate_shape=validate_shape)

def streamingConfusionMatrix(label, prediction, 
weights=None,num_classes=None):
  """
  Compute a streaming confusion matrix
  :param label: True labels
  :param prediction: Predicted labels
  :param weights: (Optional) weights (unused)
  :param num_classes: Number of labels for the confusion matrix
  :return: (percentConfusionMatrix,updateOp)
  """
  # Compute a per-batch confusion

  batch_confusion = tf.confusion_matrix(label, prediction,
                                    num_classes=num_classes,
                                    name='batch_confusion')

  count = _createLocalVariable(None,(),dtype=tf.int32)
  confusion = _createLocalVariable('streamConfusion',[num_classes, 
  num_classes],dtype=tf.int32)

  # Create the update op for doing a "+=" accumulation on the batch
  countUpdate = count.assign(count + tf.reduce_sum(batch_confusion))
  confusionUpdate = confusion.assign(confusion + batch_confusion)

  updateOp = tf.group(confusionUpdate,countUpdate)

  percentConfusion = 100 * tf.truediv(confusion,count)

  return percentConfusion,updateOp
```

You can then use it as evaluation metric in the following way:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn,metrics
#[...]

evalMetrics = {'accuracy': 
learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=metrics.streaming_accuracy),
               'confusionMatrix':learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=
                                                  lambda 
label,prediction,weights=None:                         
streamingConfusionMatrix(                                                    
label,prediction,weights,num_classes=nLabels))}
```

I suggest you use numpy.set_printoptions(precision=2,suppress=True) to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Re: your image not being meaningful - according to the docs for the [tf.summary.image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/summary/generation_of_summaries_#image), for uint8 values are unchanged (won't be normalized), and are interpreted in range [0, 255]. Have you tried re-normalizing your image to [0,255] instead of [0,1]?

Comment: Yes. This looks better. However, I am still not able to collect results from multiple batches and put it into one single confusion matrix..