# visualization of confusion matrix and some kernels of CNN in tensorbord

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am working on tensorflow 1.8 with python 2.7 version to classify a dataset of images by knowledge transfer using inception-V3. I want to use tensorbord to  visualize the confusion matrix and some kernels in convolutional layer so what I need is how to use tf.summary.FileWriter in this case ???
Thanks for HELP ...

Answer (score 0):

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617463/tensorflow-confusion-matrix-in-tensorboard) for the confusion matrix

another approach would be to use pandas or another similar lib to plot it